# Why does this pipe on my furnace blow out hot air

Tags: furnace, pipe

When the HVAC works on heating mode, this pipe and the gaps around it are blowing out warm air. What are they and why?

[image]

Comment: Worth considering: If your furnace is _inside_ the conditioned/insulated envelope of the house, even if warm air is leaking out here, it's still helping to heat your house and not being lost directly to the environment. This does strike me as odd, but I'm not sure it's anything to be too greatly worried about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I learned when I added central AC to a previous house...

These are probably condensate drain pipes.  They allow the moisture that condenses on the coils when in AC (cool) mode of operation to drain.

The right-most pipe (with the J in it) goes outside or maybe to a sump well or drain in the basement. This is the main, or primary drain.

The left pipe (the one that comes out and goes straight down) is a backup drain that water only flows out of if the primary drain is blocked.  It's opening is visible so that you can see water dripping out, as a visual indication that the primary drain is blocked.

The J-trap should hold water to prevent warm or cold air from escaping.

Comment: So, is it normal that they blow out hot/warm air?

Comment: This does a nice job of answering the "what are they?" portion of the question, but it is conspicuous in its silent treatment of the "should warm air come out of this area" part of the question. ;)

Comment: If there's not a J-trap in the drain pipe, then you would expect to have air (either warm or cold, depending on the mode of operation) coming out.  There is no J-trap that can be seen in the secondary drain pipe.  Therefore air coming out should not be unexpected.